# error: (1400, 'GetWindowRect', '\xce\xde\xd0\xa7\xb5\xc4\xb4\xb0\xbf\xda\xbe\xe4\xb1\xfa\xa1\xa3')

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple code

```
from win32gui import *
titles = set()
def foo(hwnd,mouse):
if IsWindow(hwnd) and IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) and IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
    titles.add(GetWindowText(hwnd))
EnumWindows(foo, 0)
lt = [t for t in titles if t]
lt.sort()
for t in lt:
 print t.decode("GB2312")

classname = 0
titlename = "Untitled"
hwnd = FindWindow(classname, titlename)
rect= GetWindowRect(hwnd)`
```

then Python told me that

```
---> rect= GetWindowRect(hwnd)

error: (1400, 'GetWindowRect', '\xce\xde\xd0\xa7\xb5\xc4\xb4\xb0\xbf\xda\xbe\xe4\xb1\xfa\xa1\xa3')
```

I wanna get all active windows' name and locate a window.
What can be wrong?

Comment: You should probably pass `None` instead of `0` for `classname`.

Comment: Tragedy struck me again,'0'and 'None'cause the same result.Some guys told me that Findwindow() maybe return a different hwnd to GetWindowRect's need.So Could U tells me how to fit it?Thanks.